# Want to route path in App.js according to a condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router-v4

Before routing to any component in my project, I first want to first check a condition and if that condition is satisfied then I have to render a page likewise. For example in the following code:

```
else {
  return(      
    <div>
      <Route history={browserHistory}>
        <Route exact path="/set-geography" component={Home} />
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to render "/set-geography" once my flow enters the else by trying the following code:

```
else {
window.location.href="/set-geography"
return(      
  <div>
      <Route history={browserHistory}>
        <Route exact path="/set-geography" component={Home} />
    </Route>
  </div>
);
}
```

The routing is taking place successfully but the problem is that the page is not getting stable and the page is reloading again and again. In the console I am not getting any error.
Can anybody help me in rendering the component. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why are you reloading manually with this line `window.location.href="/set-geography"`?

Comment: I don't know any other way of doing so. @Sag1v

Comment: If your condition depends on href, then don't use if/else, rather use Router to display the correct component based on path.

Comment: No my condition is not based on href, it is a general condition of checking some flag. @Sag1v

Comment: @MayankBansal what is the purpose of this line then?

Comment: @Sag1v which line ?

Comment: why are you forcing a reload instead of rendering a component? `window.location.href="/set-geography"`

Comment: I am not getting the proper way of setting the path. If this path was to be rendered from a component then it could be done easily but the problem is that I am doing this in App.js . @Sag1v

Comment: `App.js` is not a component?

Comment: @Sag1v , Yes I know App.js is not a component and that is the reason I am facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use conditional rendering

```
      {unreadMessages.length > 0 &&
        <h2>
          You have {unreadMessages.length} unread messages.
        </h2>
      }
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator